# Total sum of squares

Tags: regression, self-study, inference, linear

In the lecture notes, in order to prove that TSS=ESS+RSS.

My instructor writes that:

$$TSS = \sum_t^n (y_t -\bar{y})^2= \sum_t^n y_t^2 -n\bar{y}^2$$

I don’t understand the second equality. Instead, I would write

$$ =  \sum_t^n y_t^2 - 2\sum_t^n y_t\bar{y} + n\bar{y}^2$$.
But the instructor’s expression is different. How does he get it?

Comment: This is a big FAQ, but since it's always expressed as formulas, it's almost impossible to search for answers.  In the end it's pure algebra, depending on the observation that the residuals sum to zero.

Comment: I found the duplicate with this search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=TSS%3DESS%2BRSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_t^n (y_t -\bar{y})^2= \sum_t^n ( y_t^2 -2\bar{y}y_t + \bar{y}^2) =$$ $$=\sum_t^n  y_t^2 -2\bar{y}\sum_t^n y_t + \sum_t^n \bar{y}^2 = \sum_t^n  y_t^2 -2\bar{y}n\bar{y} + n\bar{y}^2 $$

which equals to $$ \sum_t^n y_t^2 -n\bar{y}^2$$

QED